# Uncaught Error: [RouteWrapper] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router v6 and am creating private routes for my application.

In file Route.js, I've the code

```
export default function RouteWrapper({
  element: Element,
  isPrivate,
  ...rest
}) {
  const { signed, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (loading) {
    return <div></div>;
  }

  if (!signed && isPrivate) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  if (signed && !isPrivate) {
    return <Navigate to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <Element {...props} />} />;
}
```

And in file index.js I've written as:

```
  return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/register" element={SignUp} />

        <Route path="/dashboard" element={Dashboard} isPrivate />
        <Route path="/profile" element={Profile} isPrivate />
        <Route path="/customers" element={Customers} isPrivate />
        <Route path="/new" element={New} isPrivate />
        <Route path="/new/:id" element={New} isPrivate />
      </Routes>
  );
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

- `RouteWrapper` isn't a `Route` component, and fails an invariant check by `react-router-dom`.
- `RouteWrapper` is directly rendering a `Route` component, which if the first invariant wasn't failed would trigger another invariant violation. `Route` components can only be rendered directly by the `Routes` component or another `Route` component in the case of building nested routing.

In short, in `react-router-dom@6` custom route components are no longer supported. You should instead use wrapper components/layout routes to handle this use case.

## Solution

Convert `RouteWrapper` to a wrapper component that renders an `Outlet` component for nested routed components to be rendered into.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function RouteWrapper({ isPrivate }) {
  const { signed, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (loading) {
    return <div></div>;
  }

  if (!signed && isPrivate) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  if (signed && !isPrivate) {
    return <Navigate to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  return <Outlet />; // <-- nested routes render here
}
```

Wrap the routes you want to protect with the `RouteWrapper`.

```
return (
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<RouteWrapper />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<SignIn />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />
    </Route>

    <Route element={<RouteWrapper isPrivate />}>
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
      <Route path="/customers" element={<Customers />} />
      <Route path="/new" element={<New />} />
      <Route path="/new/:id" element={<New />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
);
```

See [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={Dashboard} />
</Routes>
```

to

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Dashboard/>} />
</Routes>
```

Also if you want to keep your UI in sync with the URL use like this.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
       <Route exact path="/" element={<Dashboard/>} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Best.